# Determine the values of $p$ and $q$ for which a certain integral converges

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

How can I find for which $p$ and $q$ following integral converges:
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p+x^q}$$

I am not sure how to arrange denominator.

Comment: First idea : We can assume $p\le q$ and factor out $x^p$ in the denominator.

Comment: Assuming $p \le q$, the integrand function is $O(1/x^q)$. So we need $$\max (p,q) >1$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p>1$ then you have

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p+x^q} \; dx \leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p} \; dx$$

which converges.  Similarly, if $q>1$.

If neither $p$ nor $q$ is bigger than one, you have

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p+x^q} \; dx \geq \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+x} \; dx$$

which diverges.

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant to p>q and similarly if q>p, which I think we can cover the second case with w.l.o.g here.

Comment: No, I mean $p>1.$   If either $p$ or $q$ is bigger than one, then the integral converges.